# How to make something readable out of glBitmap()?

Tags: opengl, sdl

I cannot find and interpret anything into my own knowledge of the usage of glBitmap(). My aim for the usage of this function is to be able to render letters and text to the SDL screen using OpenGL.

My current error-filled code is:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include "functionfile.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLubyte A[14] = {
0x00,0x00,
0x60,0xc0,
0x3f,0x80,
0x00,0x00,
0x0a,0x00,
0x0a,0x00,
0x04,0x00,
};

init_ortho(640,480);

glBitmap(100,100,0,0,50,50,A);

glLoadIdentity();

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

SDL_Delay(5000);

SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}
```

which results in a white 100x100 pixels of unrecognizable fuzz in the window.

Comment: `glBitmap` is easy, but it's inflexible and slow, and the results look bad (can't antialias, no sub-pixel spacing).  You'd be much better off with textured quads (or triangle pairs, since quads are deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation of glBitmap and try to understand it. You've got some serious misconceptions.

The first two parameters of glBitmap tell it, how large the image is you feed to it. It's not the destination size. The other parameters influence how the *raster position* is adjusted. glBitmap does not scale the contents that go the screen. If your bitmap is 8x8 pixels, it will come out as 8x8 pixels.

The Red Book has a rather nice section about glBitmap: http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter08.html